# Интеграция социальных api в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1) Как правильно интегрировать эти api в wordpress ? мне нужно понять логику, а еще лучше как это сделать.

2) В моем понимании это должно выглядеть так:

- Создаем новый пост
- Функцией определяем был ли пост успешно опубликован
- Получаем урл поста
- Передаем урл функции постинга в соц сети
- Здесь нужно как-то сделать проверку во все ли соц сети удалось запостить, если нет выводим в какой произошла ошибка
- Выводим в какие соц-сети запостилось ?

3) Все это должно отображаться в панели постинга поста.

Answer (score 0):

Все это делает плагин [NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster](https://www.nextscripts.com/social-networks-auto-poster-for-wordpress/).

Comment: Мне плагин не нужен, у компании свои требования, и будет делатся персонализация, для начала им хватит линка на новость.

Comment: Этот велосипед очень сложный, не стоит его изобретать самому. Одна реализация авторизации по OAuth отнимет у вас массу времени.

Comment: Я уже все реализовал причем за сутки для всех соц сетей, осталось это только интегрировать. Встал вопрос как это правильно сделать. Так  что веслосипед готов, осталось только поставить колеса :)

Comment: Если вы уже реализовали публикацию в соцсети, то зачем об этом спрашивать? Вешайте публикацию в сети на хук `save_post` и все.

Comment: Я спрашиваю о реализации логики при интегрировании, как это лучше сделать, задача состоит в том, чтобы правильно интергировать постинг. Я представляю это так, при нажатии на кнопку публиковать, появляется алерт (как это сделанно в wp по дефауту, что статья опубликована, далее, идет след "алерт" вк, опубликованно, фб, опубликованно, од - не опубликованно. Как-то так.

Comment: Таким образом я сразу при публикации все будут видеть в какие соц-сети ушла успешно новость. В случае ошибки, показываем ошибку, что не ушла.

Comment: Т.е вы предлагаете в function.php сделать хук на save post или post published ? и там уже производить постинг. Возможно и так, но как отобразить ошибку/успех в месте где отображается надпись что пост опубликован ?

Comment: Не так. Надо делать метабоксы, в которых будете выводить информацию о том, успешно или нет опубликовано в соцсеть, с кнопкой "Повторить". Поставьте плагин, что я показал, посмотрите, как там сделано

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70314/discussion-between-webstackoverload-and-kagg-design).

Comment: А куда можно опубликовать ответ, в случае успешной, простой интеграции ?

Comment: В том же метабоксе и пишите статус

Comment: Вы не поняли, ответ на решение данной задачи, может кому-то пригодится ?

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, где сузьте его до рамок простой интеграции с сетями и сами же опубликуйте к нему ответ.

Comment: Вопрос, нужно ли запоминать ссылку на пост в соц сети или нет ? хотел бы понять плюсы и минусы, допустим мы делаем пост, он отправляется в соц сети, а также запоминается в дополнительных полях самого поста wp.